# Conditional Formatting with multiple values in a single cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make a color highlight rule in excel when there are repeat numbers. Some of the cells have more than one value. The values in those cells are separated either by a "/" or a ",". Is there a way to make this conditional formatting work? Whenever I try, it doesn't recognize the cells with multiple values as numbers.

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Can't see the picture on that link. Just lots of ads :/

Comment: Try to provide the images in your post. Or the raw text. It will make it easier to read and help you.

Comment: @KalelWade and JNevill. New user, with not enough rep to post images. I just edited the post with the images.

Comment: @pnuts Yes to integers. No to single digits. It will range from 1 to as high as 200.